# How to send ajax request without specifying port of REST API running in ubuntu on digitalocean?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have created one digitalocean ubuntu droplet and deployed springboot REST Service on that. When i am trying to fire an AJAX call without specifying the port number. It says connection refused . But after specifying port number it is correctly hitting to the service.

Example :

```
http://zyx.site/shortener - This doesn't works
```

However :

```
http://zyx.site:8080/shortener - This  works
```

What change should i make and where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ommit the Port in your call, it uses Port `80` automatically.
(Or `433`when you use `https://`).

You have to expose your API on port 80 / 433 if you want to ommit it.